# Views Below the cell?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, ios4

How can we integrate UIScrollview,UIView,Textview under TableviewCell.for example if we press button which is in tableview cell, the UITextview must come under that cell…(it wont go to the Next Page)..

Comment: Can you post some code to illustrate what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to add a new cell under the one that was clicked. This new cell would have on its content view the `UITextview`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Insert the new cell containing the text view on indexPath.row+1
}
```